# PHPUnit Selenium with the Grinder and GWT

Tags: gwt, selenium, phpunit, selenium-rc, grinder

I've setup a Selenium test case using the [PHPUnit extension for Selenium](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/selenium.html).
I've executed the test case and it works perfectly.

Now I'd like to do some performance tests with [The Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net).
In other words, I'd like to use the TCPProxy process provided by the Grinder framework and execute my Selenium test multiple times in parallel. I'm able to record the entire Selenium test with the Grinder TCPProxy. But when I want to run the generated python script from the Grinder console, I notice that some GET, or POST requests always raise an error.

My web application is developed with GWT (Google Web Toolkit). So there are obviously lots of asynchronous requests. Is this where the problem might come from? Does anyone already has experienced with The Grinder and GWT?

All little help would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing "wait/sleep" period per action/activity to accommodate worse case slow rpc request scenarios. If that does not address the situation then you might have add some details after digging through your errors.

Give Selenium a try as it emulates user interaction on browser and hence will not encounter XSRF based issues as you are facing with a server side approach with Grinder.

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't solve the issue. After checking the grinder log files I see that the HTTP error raised by my POST requests is 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: Then you need to check your server logs and update your question with the details.

Comment: OK. I saw in the grinder log files that the error raised by the POST request was 500 Internal Server Error. So I went server side to see what is really happening, and there it is:

**Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call: java.lang.SecurityException: Blocked request without GWT permutation header (XSRF attack?)**

So I think my python script is OK. It's just that my request is blocked by jboss for security reasons. Does anybody know how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Its not jboss. XSRF tokens get generated by GWT Client side and gets authenticated by GWT Servlet before rpc response.